# How to hide Server parameter in response header of Azure app Service?

Tags: azure, httpresponse, azure-web-app-service

We have deployed our service on Azure.

For the Security purpose, in web.config we have set the following parameter:

```html
 <security>
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader ="true"></requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

I am testing this on Postman tool, when the request is send successfully (200 request OK), the ***Server*** is hidden in response.

**Issue:**

Now for the same request, if I change the hostname (say xyz (anything: fake))
then in response header it shows as

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5But.png)

I think it is coming from IIS (Azure).

Hope anyone can help me,

Thank you

Comment: I am also needing to remove the server header, along with others. I've found that not only fake routes that result in 404s show still show the headers, but also any static files (css files, etc.). However, network data calls correctly hide the headers. Did you have any luck on this issue since you posted?

Answer (score 1):

Azure App Services (which is what you're using, based on your screenshots) use multi-tenant environments to host apps. SSL offloading happens in VMs called Front End servers (which run on IIS10 and use the ARR module), before hitting the Workers which actually host your running application.

The routing/load balancing between a Front End server and your one of your workers is performed based on the "Host" HTTP header in the incoming request. Without the header, the Front End server does not know which workers are allocated to your site, so can't route the request.

This is why you get that "404 Site Not Found" response - The FE sends it.
That's also why you see the headers, your web.config was never reached.

**TLDR:**

Without the proper Host header, your application is never actually reached, a different piece of the multi-tenant puzzle responds with 404 Site Not Found as routing breaks.